# Filling the html form fields through servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So the question is like we manipulate the values of the form fields through servlets by using `request.getParameter()` can we do the other way round i.e set the form feild values fromthe servlet itself?

Basically what I am trying to do is to create a dropdown and some textboxes. the dropdown gets the ids from the database , when user selects a particular id, the text boxes should get filled with the other values from database for that id so the user can either edit them or leave unchanged accordingly.

For ex: The html code is:

```
 <form action="GetValues">
<select name="ids"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
<input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
<form action="Save">
    Product name:<input type="text" name="name" id="tb1"/></br>
Price:<input type="text" name="price" id="tb1"/>

<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

The Getvalues servlet establishes the database connection and gets the values of name and price from the datbase which I can do, but **how to display those values in the two textboxes?**

I can than make the `Save.java` servlet to get the values from textfields and update into the database.

I am not at all comfortable using JSP scriptlets. I want to do this using servlets only.

I know I could have created textboxes using the servlet itself but that won't work for me because that makes my jquery on the form die.

Like we do in javascript:

```
var x="hii";
document.getElementById("tb1").value=x;
```

Is there anything like this in Java too?

Comment: Are you using jsp's ?

Comment: yes but i am not comfortable with writing java code there. not much experinced in that, if that is the only way, you will need to explain it

Comment: Have you heard about AJAX ?

Comment: yes ofcourse i have. But never coded any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you requested no scriptlets, but IMO this is the easiest way to do it.

In your servlet, set a request attribute as such:

`request.setAttribute("attributeName", attributeValue);`

Then in your jsp, you can access the attributeValue like this:

`<%= request.getAttribute("attributeName") >`

Edit: For the followup question in the comment, here is how you can show the IDs in the select box using scriptlets:

First, set the list of IDs in the servlet:

```
List<String> idList = ...;
request.setAttribute("idList", list);
```

Then in your JSP, construct the select field as follows:

```
<select name="ids">
  <% 
    List<String> idList = request.getAttribute("idList");
    for(String id : idList) {
  %>
      <option><%=id></option>
  <%
    }
  %>
</select>
```

Comment: request.setAttribute("attributeName", attributeValue); is attribute name the name of textbox?

Comment: how will it get displayed in the textbox?

Comment: The scriptlet tag will be replaced with the value of the attribute.  So, when you are constructing your textbox do the following: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<%=request.getAttribute("attributeName")>"><br>

Comment: hey! one more thing how do i add ids from database into the already created dropdown in jsp form?

Answer (score 0):

> . the dropdown gets the ids from the database , when user selects a particular id, the text boxes should get filled with the other values from database for that id so the user can either edit them or leave unchanged accordingly.

That is the perfect place to use a AJAX call. Please fire a AJAX request and get the values from Database.

Comment: 0 knowledge about ajax. don't know any code just the theory part. only if you could explain the whole code

Comment: Sorry , I can't without any efforts from you. That's not the way SO works.

Comment: anything other than ajax?

Comment: Jsp or Ajax, as far as I know.

Comment: and how would you do it in jsp?

Comment: @Nivedita Have you even search any examples before asking a question ?

Comment: yes ofcourse but those were complex codes and deviated from the topic a bit and some extra concepts were required for them